What does the Meet Area and Control stat do?
When leveling up a custom character in Mario Golf for Game Boy Color, what does the "Meet Area and Control" stat do?


Meet Area
The larger the meet area the better, this makes it easier to hit a better shot,
since point 2 on the power gauge will be wider.
Control
The less waver the better, as you will hit the ball steadier. Increasing control stat will reduce the waver effect.
Source, Gamefaqs

What is the waver effect?

I really don't have a clue, never played this game. I think it means that the ball is less affected by the wind. I don't see what other element could control your shots.
